# Is there a way to JOIN a table consisting of two tables UNIONed together?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    a.First_Name
   ,b.Last_Name

FROM table a
JOIN table b
UNION table c
ON a.ID=b.ID
```

I'm not even sure how the syntax would be for this. Basically what I want is to UNION table b and c then JOIN the new table to table a.

Comment: Union the tables? Do they have exactly the same structure? If so, why is this two tables and not one? Sounds like a bad data model.

Comment: They don't have the same structure. I actually just want two columns out of each table, making the data types match up.

Comment: On a sidenote: Always when using `UNION` consider whether `UNION ALL` would suffice. `UNION` does the same as `UNION ALL` (glue results together) plus removes duplicates. So ask yourself: are there really duplicates to remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the union a *subquery*:

```
SELECT 
    a.First_Name
   ,bc.Last_Name
FROM table a
JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM table b
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM table c
    ) AS bc
ON a.ID=bc.ID
```

Note that the subquery must have its own alias (`bc` in this case) which should be referenced in the join clause and the select (meaning you can't reference tables `b` or `c` directly outside of the subquery).

Comment: Ah yes thank you! I knew there was a way but I just could not for the life of me think of it

Comment: Depending on the actual data `UNION ALL` might be possible/correct (and will be probably more efficient)

Answer (score 1):

You can join a subquery:

```
SELECT 
  a.First_Name,
  bc.Last_Name
FROM a
JOIN 
(
  SELECT ID, Last_Name FROM b
  UNION
  SELECT ID, Last_Name FROM c
) bc ON bc.ID = a.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of a union can be join to others table if you the the proper  join clause

You could use this sintax

```
  select a.col1, t.name 
  from table3 c 
  inner join (
        select id, name1 as name
        from table1 a
        union id, name2
        from table2 b
  ) t on. t.id = a.id
```